# Разбираюсь с ключевым словом this

Tags: java

Вот этот вот код

```
public class Leaf {
    int i = 0;
    Leaf increment() {
      i++;
      return this;
    }
}
```

И вот этот вот:

```
public class Leaf {
    Leaf a = new Leaf();
    int i = 0;
    Leaf increment() {
        i++;
        return a;
    }  
}
```

По сути одно и тоже? Они эквивалентны?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Нет, они разные.

В первом случае метод `increment` возвращает объект класса из которого был вызван (`return this;`)

Во втором случае он возвращает внутренний объект класса, из кторого вы вызываете метод. При этом переменная `i` возвращённого класса не увеличена.

Answer (score 5):

Это дав ***совершенно*** разных кода. Ключевое слово `this` внутри метода класса ссылается на конкретный экземпляр, для которого был вызван метод. Например:

```
class A {
    public void method() { /* ... */ };
}

A a1, a2;
a1.method();  // Внутри method this==a1.
a2.method();  // Внутри method this==a2.
```

Ключевое слово `this` неявно подставляется при обращении к членам (переменным и методам) класса. Точнее говоря, компилятор *пытается* подставить `this` перед любой переменной и методом, и если ему это не удаётся, ищет объекты в другой области. Например:

```
int i = 100;
class B {
    private int i = 1;
    public int method() {
        return ++i;  // Будет интерпретировано как ++(this->i).
    }
}

B b;
System.out.println(b.method());  // Выведет 2.
System.out.println(i);           // Выведет 100.
```

Учитывая всё вышесказанное, Ваш код эквивалентен следующему:

```
public class Leaf {
    int i = 0;
    Leaf increment() {
      (this->i)++;
      return this;
    }
}

public class Leaf {
    Leaf a = new Leaf();
    int i = 0;
    Leaf increment() {
        (this->i)++;
        return a;
    }  
}
```

Видно, что это разный код. В обоих случаях инкрементируется член текущего экземпляра класса, но в первом возвращается текущий экземпляр, а во втором - совершенно иной.